# MeteorJS - Template won't rerender after resubscription

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a gallery application, and I have a categories bar such that when I click one of the categories, I want the gallery to only show images that are in the selected category.

This is gallery.html

```
<template name="gallery">
   <div class="container col-sm-10"> 
   {{>gallerypost}}
    <div class="grid master">
    {{#each images}}
      <div class="grid-item">

       <div class="galleryimage" style="">
        {{#if isPortrait this.orientation}}
        <img src="{{c.url (nameHelper this.name) width=473 height=646   crop="scale"}}" class="img img-responsive" />
        {{else}}
        <img src="{{c.url (nameHelper this.name) width=646 height=473 crop="scale"}}" class="img img-responsive" />
        {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

client.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('allimages');
Session.setDefault('category', null);
Tracker.autorun(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('categoryimages', Session.get('category'));
   console.log('this is working');
});
```

publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('allimages', function(){
  return ImageInfo.find();
});
Meteor.publish('categoryimages', function(category){
  return ImageInfo.find({category: category});
});
```

So I know the my Session variable works, as I have tested it out in the console. But for some reason the database is not updating. Is it because of the grid framework (Masonsry) that I'm using? What's causing the database to not subscribe to the specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `reloadItems` inside your autorun would help http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems

```
$('.container').masonry('reloadItems');
```

Comment: The database itself is not updating... whats wrong with my pub-sub setup?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your publications. Where's the code that updates the database?

Comment: 'click #categories': function(e, t){
    e.preventDefault();
    var keyword = $(e.target).text();
    var pos = keyword.indexOf("(");
    keyword = keyword.slice(0,pos-1);

    Session.set('category', keyword);
  }

Comment: so pretty much i get the keyword from a DOM list, then I just set the Session to that keyword, and the code in client.js is supposed to reactively resubscribe whenever the session variable changes right...?